# Where can I find the WAMP error log?

Tags: apache, ssl, wamp, httpd.conf

I am using WAMP2.2 on Windows. I need to set up SSL port on my server. My Apache, WAMP and site work well without SSL. But when I uncomment the line

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

in my **httpd.conf**, the WAMP Server is not working anymore.(It remains orange when I restart). I assume that something is wrong with the configurations in **httpd-ssl.conf**. But I am wondering how I can find the error that doesn't let WAMP to start properly. Is there any error log file for WAMP?

I found these errors on **wamp/logs/apache-error.log**:

```
Script not found or unable to start: wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2/cgi-bin/php
Script not found or unable to start: wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2/cgi-bin/php5
Script not found or unable to start: wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2/cgi-bin/php-cgi
Script not found or unable to start: wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2/cgi-bin/php4
```

Are these errors related to SSL configuration. And if so what should I do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I am trying to run httpd -t I am getting Syntax error! I checked the error in wamp/logs/apache-error and found these lines: Script not found or unable to start: wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2/cgi-bin/php wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2/cgi-bin/php5wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2/cgi-bin/php5

Answer (score 45):

Apache in WAMPServer writes errors to the `C:\wamp\logs` folder or `C:\wamp64\logs` if you are using the 64bit version, as does `MYSQL` and `PHP`

If Apache or MySQL find errors before they can open their own `error.log` it will write errors to the `Windows Event Log` as well.

Try opening a command window and

```
>CD c:\wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z\bin
```

Then run

```
httpd -t
```

That should check the config and return you any errors to the command window.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I am trying to run httpd -t I am getting Syntax error! I checked the error in wamp/logs/apache-error and found these lines: Script not found or unable to start: wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2/cgi-bin/php wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2/cgi-bin/php5

Comment: That looks like you have edited `httpd.conf` with notepad and it has merged 2 lines. Some files went out with UNIX line endings which means you have to use a editor that understands uninx line endings like `notepad++`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see a brief log of Wamp services:

Right click on wampserver icon-> Tools-> Check state of services