# .htaccess file blocks loading index page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, internal-server-error

Since am new to `htacess` so i generated `htacess` file [here](http://htaccesser.apacheblog.de/index.php) and bellow is my code

```
Order allow,deny
<Files .htaccess .htpasswd .htuser .htgroups >
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule !mod_ssl.c>
Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ - [F]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Wget [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} CherryPickerSE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} CherryPickerElite [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} EmailCollector [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} EmailSiphon [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} EmailWolf [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ExtractorPro 
RewriteRule ^.*$ deny.html [L]
ErrorDocument 400 400.php
ErrorDocument 401 401.php
ErrorDocument 403 403.php
ErrorDocument 404 404.php
ErrorDocument 500 405.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Produces the error:

```
[Wed Jan 07 19:09:22.207084 2015] [core:alert] [pid 5032:tid 964] [client 200.195.156.150:43841] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Multiple <Files> arguments not (yet) supported.
```

and error `mod_rewrite` even configured [following method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995545/htaccess-rewriteengine-not-allowed-here)

when i delete mt `htacess` file and run my server my index page open , all `ErrorDocument` page and `htacess` and index page are in `root` folder can any one help me whats wrong

Comment: Look in your error log. If there's an Internal Server Error, it will be detailed there.

Comment: First remove all code and add one by one line to debug and also use the error log to check what is the error.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski when i run without `htacess` page laods

Comment: @learn I understand that. You need to look in the error log to find out why this .htaccess is failing.

Comment: @learn the problem is, that your HTACCESS throws an Error and loading isn't possible anymore .. so take a look in the apache error.log to find and solve the error(s)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski since am new programming language where do i get error log

Comment: @learn That depends on your server environment or your host. If you have a VPS it would be in `/var/log/apach2` or `/var/log/httpd` probably. If you have shared hosting, consult their documentation.

Comment: is there any way or how do i create `htacess` file

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski can you tell me how to find error log in localhost so that it will be easy to find instead server

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite? I am suspecting that you didn't and that it does not understand the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives.

Comment: You still haven't said what platform you're working. The error log on `localhost` could be in many possible places.

Comment: @Sumurai8 so what are the rules i should follow when i add `htacess` file since am new i just upload (php,css,js,image file) via FTP and i didn't do anything on server

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski in `localhost` i get this error what do??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131236/how-do-you-enable-mod-rewrite - Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713001/where-can-i-find-the-wamp-error-log if you are using WAMP.

Comment: I still don't get how people run web servers and don't have basic pricinples down to check the error log when there is an issue. You can't guess your way through development.

Comment: @learn In localhost, just as on a production web server, you _check the error log_. I cannot tell you where to find that log, because you have not told us what OS you use on localhost to develop this.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski am using wamp server in windows 8 to run php files in  local host

Comment: @learn Then [here is how to find the error log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713001/where-can-i-find-the-wamp-error-log)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski last help when add `htacess` file in server what are all things i should change to activate my `htacess` file working

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `::1 - - [07/Jan/2015:14:05:17 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 614
::1 - - [07/Jan/2015:14:05:31 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 614
::1 - - [07/Jan/2015:14:05:31 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 614` my error log

Comment: @learn that looks like the contents of an access log, not of an error log.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski am sry here `[Wed Jan 07 19:09:22.207084 2015] [core:alert] [pid 5032:tid 964] [client 200.195.156.150:43841] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Multiple <Files> arguments not (yet) supported.`

Comment: It clearly tells you `<Files .htaccess .htpasswd .htuser .htgroups >` is not supported. Which is correct, you need to have the pipe delimiter in there for multiple types. http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-filesmatch-and-files-in-htaccess.html

Comment: @PanamaJack so whats the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try using FilesMatch instead of Files, I think this was the part generating an error.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|htuser|htgroups)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I left rest of a code unchanged.

```
<IfModule !mod_ssl.c>
Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ - [F]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Wget [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} CherryPickerSE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} CherryPickerElite [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} EmailCollector [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} EmailSiphon [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} EmailWolf [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ExtractorPro 
RewriteRule ^.*$ deny.html [L]
ErrorDocument 400 400.php
ErrorDocument 401 401.php
ErrorDocument 403 403.php
ErrorDocument 404 404.php
ErrorDocument 500 405.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: Other than the first line missing, this is identical to the code in the question. I just did a diff on the two

Comment: I guess I should have been more precise, sorry. I suggested using FilesMatch directive instead of Files - it is a preferred way when dealing with multiple files (and it seems that this part was causing an error).

Comment: @learn Could you please post a log error generated after applying changes I suggested? Seems a bit odd that the error is exactly the same...

Comment: @Poodel `C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: OK. The problem with files is gone, now you need to enable mod_rewrite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144634/htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-m

Comment: am almost done only one `C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Multiple <Files> arguments not (yet) supported.`

Comment: @Poodel your above code redirect me to `www.domain.com` how to disable that

Comment: It is because of this fragment of your code:

    `Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/`

Not sure what was the idea behind this, but if you don't want to redirect, just delete this fragment.

Answer (score -1):

Remove all Code from .htaccess and only keep the following code.

```
RewriteEngine  on
ErrorDocument 400 400.php
ErrorDocument 401 401.php
ErrorDocument 403 403.php
ErrorDocument 404 404.php
ErrorDocument 500 405.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: but i need all `rewrite` rule

Comment: Are you use any cms? like wordpress

Comment: @CmsCoders If I may suggest something, please take a look at [this help item](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Some of your answers are just of dramatic quality, and after going through all of them I couldn't find any that I would consider upvoting. I would suggest going through your old answers and editing them to improve their quality.

Comment: sure i will take care next time